# before event shutil copy2

Tags: regex, python-3.x, directory

I want to use my own copy2 function when calling `shutil.copytree`. I will be using a regex on the dst to create a new dst(copy and rename). I see the function header for copy2 as `shutil.copy2(src, dst, *, follow_symlinks=True)`.
If I were to create the following:

```
def my_copy2(???):
    return copy2(src, newdst...)
```

What should my function header look like, and what will I call `copy2` with? I am uncertain what happens to the empty `*` and the symlink argument, i.e. do I care?

This works, but not same function signature as copy2:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import shutil

def copy_and_rename(src,dst) :
    return shutil.copy2(src, dst.replace("pdf","zzz"))

SRC_DIR="srcjunk"
DEST_DIR="destjunk"
shutil.copytree(SRC_DIR, DEST_DIR, copy_function=copy_and_rename)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can import the module inside the function or you can do it on the script. The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/shutil.html#shutil.copy) doesn't explain what is `*`. I would omit it.

```
from shutil import copy2
def my_copy2(src, newdst, ...)
    return copy2(src, newdst, ...)
```

Or with the import inside (also you could just do `import shutil` and then import with `shutil.copy2`):

```
def my_copy2(src, newdst, ...)
    from shutil import copy2
    return copy2(src, newdst, ...)
```

You must give enough parameters to your function that `copy2` is able to run. 
Abut using regex means that before using the string you could prepare it, adding the suffix, or adding the path where do you want to store it. This can be done inside your function or outside.

Comment: Program gave no errors with def my_copy2(src, newdst). What is "..."? And what is a blank asterisk mean anyway? I receive invalid syntax with the "..."

Comment: ... are other arguments that you need for copy2 or for the regex treatment. About the asterisk I don't know the meaning...

Comment: I receive invalid syntax with the "..."

Comment: Try reading this [manual](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/os/python-the-shutil-module). You must substitute `...`   by the arguments. Also if you have an error in your code, it would be better if you paste the error in your question.

Comment: def my_copy2(src,dst, ...) :
  SyntaxError: invalid syntax (array points to ellipses)

Comment: Could please you edit your post pasting the code you used and the error?